# Delete a list using SharePoint 2010 CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, csom, sharepoint-clientobject

I am trying to delete a list that contains documents using the SharePoint 2010 CSOM and am using the following code:

```
var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Project Documents");
list.DeleteObject();

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

But I always get the exception "This list cannot be deleted".  The list is empty, but still I am not able to delete it.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that all the error says?  Does it not say why the list can't be deleted?  Can you delete the list through the browser?

Comment: @Servy, yes that is all the error says, it is particularly unhelpful.  However, I did notice that I don't have the option to delete the list through the browser either.  Is there a way I can programmatically give myself permission to delete the list?  I will be running this code for ~20K lists.

Comment: It looks like if I set $list.AllowDeletion = $True in PowerShell, I can delete the list.  Which means I have to write a script to set that field for all existing lists, and also change the code that creates the lists to set that upon list creation.  Thanks @Servy!